# 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, dart

I trying to store list to local database. Example

```
[{id: 29, inspection_id: 25}]  // output for time:i['inspection']['time']
```

I use this code

```
   var value = json.decode(response.body);
      for (var i in value['requests']) {
      await _dao.insert(ABC(time:i['inspection']['time']));
    }
```

If `i['inspection']['time]` not empty, it works fine,but if it is empty, `[]`, I get type `'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'`

How can I check if it is empty, it will not insert into database so I can get rid of this error?

Please help, I'm crying.

**Edit**

```
 var a = i['current_inspection']['time'].toString();
 print("a "+a);
```

The value get printed, but if the list is empty, it will throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably because you are missing an end quote for your string, that would explain the error message, try:

```dart
var value = json.decode(response.body);
      for (var i in value['requests']) {
      await _dao.insert(ABC(time:i['inspection']['time']));
    }
```

On another note, to check if a list is empty in dart, just use List.isEmpty.

Use a ternary operator and check if the list is empty like so:

```dart
 var a = i['current_inspection']['time'].isEmpty? #default value: i['current_inspection']['time'].toString();
```

This should work.

Comment: Typo. Please check again.

Comment: Just add a conditional validation for if list isEmpty? Suppose the list is empty what default value would you like to assign?